# Validating phone number in android

Tags: android

I want to validate phone number.
`Phone Number = countryCode+areaCode+PhoneNumber`.
I want to know what is the standard minimum and maximum length of Phone Number so i could validate it. 
-thanks

Comment: That actually depends on the country, so it's not a simple problem.

Comment: so what to do? any solution? thanks

Comment: You probably need something like https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^[+]?[0-9]{10,13}$
```

Or this:

```
PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber("+912012185234");
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on if you are accepting [any country code](http://countrycode.org/) or are looking for specific country code/s.

Then how many digits you are expecting for area code and then the actual phone number and whether these are being fetched as separate variables or one string.

So after answering these question. You can [use (test your code)](http://www.regexr.com/) [regex (learn how to use it)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), (and as @Basil has suggested), but vary the length (and possibly digits, if there are limited country codes)  accordingly.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10342411/3956566) is a good answer to using regex in android.