# How to make pattern for string in android

Tags: java, android, regex

I want make own pattern matcher.

I want allow like this characters only `TN 08 AB 2233`. How can I make a pattern for this?

I tried like below but its erase all characters what I type in edit text

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{4,5}[A-Z]{7,8}[0-9]{10,13}$
```

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input/11838715#11838715

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327901/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-android

Comment: `[A-Z]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{2}\\s[0-9]{4}`

Comment: Seems like a Tamil Nadu car number.

Comment: `{7,8}` repeats the previous token 7 or 8 times. It won't denote the position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 ^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{4}$
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is something like this `^[A-Z]{2}\\s\\d{2}\\s[A-Z]{2}\\s\\d{4}$`

for explanation, the values in the curly brackets are not idices, but number of values.

so, `[A-Z]{1,2}` means a value between A-Z at least ond and max two times. 
`[0-9]{4,5}` means a value between 0 an 9 at least 4 and max 5 times.
also you are missing the white spaces in your regex, if they are mandatory.
`\s` defines any white space, the second `\` is to escape the other `\`.
if the are not mandatory, you can ignore them by a `?` like this `^[A-Z]{2}(\\s)?\\d{2}(\\s)?[A-Z]{2}(\\s)?\\d{4}$`. so they can be there, but do not have to be.