# how to make this regular excepression work with java - android?

Tags: java, android, regex

How to use this with `String.matches(...........)`

`^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$`

It would match the following examples and much more:

```
18005551234     
1 800 555 1234    
+1 800 555-1234

+86 800 555 1234    
1-800-555-1234    
1 (800) 555-1234    
(800)555-1234    
(800) 555-1234    
(800)5551234
800-555-1234
800.555.1234
800 555 1234x5678    
8005551234 x5678    
1    800    555-1234    
1----800----555-1234
```

Comment: here is link of this regex
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number

Comment: Escape the backslashes. I'd also recommend replacing all `\d` with `[0-9]`. In `matches`, you do not need `^` and `$`. See [*How to use regular expression in android*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327901/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to escape the first `+` in your pattern.

Then, make delimiters optional and allow more than one in consequence to match all variants like `1 (800) 555-1234`, `(800) 555-1234`, and `18005551234`.

The regex would be:

```
^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: ?x(\d+))?\s*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pV4hL9/1

Finally, in Java, escape backslashes with backslashes: https://ideone.com/L6bNA9

Answer (score 0):

You could use: [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)
And if you're developing for android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or later it is built in within the android framework.

*(This was mentioned before by someone else, but they removed the answer)*