# Issues in car Registration Number Validations

Tags: android

How to validate the car registration number in android.I am giving like this every time it shows toast message.I want like this AP05TB3456.can any one solve this isssue?

```
String numPlate = "(([A-Za-z]){2,3}(|-)(?:[0-9]){1,2}(|-)(?:[A-Za-z]) {2}(|-)([0-9]){1,4})|(([A-Za-z]){2,3}";

if (reg_no.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")||!reg_no.getText().toString().contentEquals(numPlate))
           {
               Toast.makeText(MoreInfoactvity.this, "Please Enter Valid Registration Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below regex.

```
(([A-Za-z]){2,3}(|-)(?:[0-9]){1,2}(|-)(?:[A-Za-z]){2}(|-)([0-9]){1,4})|(([A-Za-z]){2,3}(|-)([0-9]){1,4})4
```

**Exmple :**

```
GJ 05 AB 8460
```

Comment: its not working for me will u comment total syntax please

Comment: !reg.getText().toString.equals((([A-Za-z]){2,3}(|-)(?:[0-9]){1,2}(|-)(?:[A-Za-z]){2}(|-)([0-9]){1,4})|(([A-Za-z]){2,3}(|-)([0-9]){1,4})4) this iis right syntax or not?

Comment: @Anilkumar No you have to Implement pattern and then Match with your text. see here is good Explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327901/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-android